# access data from ajax function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope, global-variables

My MWE data.js looks like this:

```
var data = [];
function initdata(){
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data){
            data.push("test");
        },
        ...
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    initdata();
    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(data[0]);
}
```

But the console says, `data.length` is `0` and `data[0]` is `undefined`. How can I access data from an ajax function in another function?

Comment: *"How can I access data from an ajax function in another function?"* You pass the data to that other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.ajax()` is asynchronous, so by the time it completes its request and runs `data.push('test')` your `console.log(data.length)` has already completed.
A way to fix this is to use a callback:

```
function initdata(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(result) { // or just success: callback,
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initdata(function(data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        console.log(data[0]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to achieve this same thing with $.when?
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/